# Frame rate too slow when creating movie from individually-downloaded JPEGs

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, slideshow

I have a directory that is continously filled with jpg images.
I want to display these images like a movie in a webpage.

What I've tried is:

```
function slideit() { 
 $.get("test.php", function(show) { if(show != "") { 
 document.getElementById("movie").innerHTML="<img src=\"data:image/jpg;base64," + show + "\" />", 
 setTimeout('slideit()', 0) } } ); };
```

The PHP file is

```
function getrunpic()
    {
    $file=trim(shell_exec('ls directory | sort -n | grep jpg | head -1'));
    $file="directory/".$file;
    $imagedata = file_get_contents($file);
    $pic = base64_encode($imagedata);
    unlink($file);
    return $pic;
    }

echo getrunpic();
```

I also tried it with JSON encodeing.

The problem is that the data transfer from php to javascript takes too long. (shows only about 8 pics per sec; I need 25).

Does anybody have an idea to make the process faster?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `setTimeout(slideit, 0)` is equivalent but much more efficient than `setTimeout('slideit()', 0)`

Comment: http://socket.io/ - Try this one ,but i really doubt the results on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way to go. You should create the movie server-side and then stream it client-side. This is the only way to take advantage of the most basic functions of a codec, like compression, keyframes, etc, and to be able to guarantee at least some consistency to the viewer.

See this: [Create Video File using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892308/create-video-file-using-php)

Comment: The images are displayed on an Iphone. When i use a movieclip with a HTML player, the movie is shown in Full size and that is not what we want becouse the other site info is lost then.

Comment: Anyway, wrt your code, at least do preload images and use the timer function to display them only. So you should try to load as many images as you can, feed a buffer, and use the timer function only to display them...

Comment: I can't imagine this to be the only way to stream video to an iPhone. Maybe you should ask a different question on how to better achieve your goal? Have you looked into the html video tag, and such?

Comment: Yes I did. But iphone only can display movies in full size. So the other site info is lost.

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699552/html5-inline-video-on-iphone-vs-ipad-browser

Comment: This works with ipad but not with iphone. sorry. Already tried this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will be the transfer "from php to javascript" - it's more likely to be the transfer from the server to the browser that's causing the issue. To make 25 individual HTTP requests per second, each one would need to be done in under 40ms (although you may get slightly longer with concurrent browser connections and overlapping requests).

Loading yahoo.com's home page and watching Firebug's "Net" panel, filtered to show just the HTTP requests for images, an average request shows the following times:

- 1ms blocking
- 1ms DNS lookup
- 125ms connecting
- 124ms waiting
- 116ms receiving

... which means that you're always going to struggle to get 25 frames / second using individual requests.

Have you considered using a streaming media (video) format? There are some [tutorials](http://www.mediacollege.com/video/streaming/overview.html) over at [mediacollege.com](http://www.mediacollege.com) and more information on [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media).

Comment: The images are displayed on an Iphone. When i use a movieclip with a HTML player, the movie is shown in Full size and that is not what we want becouse the other site info is lost then

Comment: I have called the script from the server itself and it was as slow as caling it from any browser. calling the php script alone with a loop returns the base64 image much faster.(35/sec)