# Video from images PHP

Tags: php, image, video, ffmpeg, gif

How can I make video from images in PHP? I know that I need FFMPEG , I have this binary (linux user). one of the SO question [Create Video File using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892308/create-video-file-using-php)  theres gif image, instead of gif I need sequence of images. audio is not important. I had several experiments using GD library with images but video is new for me.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google first! A query for `video from images php` will turn up everything you need....

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks mate, i know how to google, I always try to get first aid from google. all links are red but i can't come to this idea. and possible duplicate using shell, i need to do from php..  http://www.imagetovideo.com/ like this site,  it's best solution for me, upload and then pack as video.

Comment: You can execute shell commands from within PHP, that's likely to be the best way. And there is an extension: http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Oh, thanks, I didn't know that php can execute shell commands, i'm starter, because of this i do this experiments to increase my xp. thanks, i 'll take a look.